# Android: Error retrieving parent for item in style

Tags: android, xml, styles

in my res/values/styles.xml file i get this error: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.

in my android manifest i have made the minsdkversion="11" and targetsdkversion="18"
i do not know what the problem is. Here is the xml file

```
  <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
 </style>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
 </style>

 <!-- ActionBar styles -->
 <style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
 </style>

 <!-- ActionBar title text -->
 <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
 </style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// try this 
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    **colors.xml**  // define here color which are use in your style
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <color name="actionbar_text">#yourcolorcode</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: now it shows this:<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item> and and error saying:error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionMenuTextColor' with value 
 '@color/actionbar_text').

Comment: I have edited my ans see and error cmg bcz your have not define this color in colors.xml i have show example in ans plz check it...

Comment: now in the colors.xml file it gives me this error:Error: String types not allowed (at 'actionbar_text' with value 
 'rgb').

Comment: which color your wan to set?

Comment: i want to set the color red

Comment: set this <color name="actionbar_text">#FF0000</color>